# remove project name prefix from spring redirect url

Tags: java, spring, nginx, redirect, jakarta-ee

I use nginx reverse proxy to connect tomcat and nginx config is:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name magnet.s-m.local;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080/magnet/;
      proxy_cookie_path /magnet /;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

every this is ok but when I want to redirect user spring add project name to redirect path.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginCheck(HttpSession session, @RequestParam("username") String user, @RequestParam("password") String password){
    session.setAttribute("username",user);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

this code redirect to `http://magnet.s-m.local/magnet/home` but I want to redirect `http://magnet.s-m.local/home`

if I use `RedirectView` it's work nice but using `redirect:/home` is better because I can decide to redirect or load jsp file if login failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `proxy_redirect` and `proxy_set_header Host` parameters from your nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080/magnet/;
    proxy_cookie_path /magnet /;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

You also can specify the [`proxy_redirect`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) more in detail, but it should be activated.